# So I encouter problem in deploying my project it said MIME

Tags: deployment, cloud, mime-types, mime

So I'm deploying my project thru a cloud server so i just git clone my project in github and after cloning it and checking the website it says this error in the console.log

Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

So in my file structure is the
index.html, vite-config.js

so this is my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="./src/assets/Scholarlink Logo (40 x 40 px).svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Scholarlink</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="./src/main.jsx"></script>
        <script type="module" src="./vite-config.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```